# Is It Possible to Have a Local .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, ventura

I'd like to have a different `PATH` for a project, and I was wondering if it's possible to have a local `.bash_profile` for a specific folder and its subfolders. Is this even possible?

Comment: How is bash supposed to recognize, that it needs to do a specific setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) for that.

> direnv is an extension for your shell. It augments existing shells with a new feature that can load and unload environment variables depending on the current directory.

Other solutions can be found here in [superuser stack](https://superuser.com/questions/521657/zsh-automatically-set-environment-variables-for-a-directory)